# How to if isset checking in PHP switch?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="my">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
$ali = $_POST['my'];
}
switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
}
?>
```

The problem is that i have error when i want to open the window !

> Notice: Undefined variable: ali in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 11

How to check the value into the switch ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `$_POST['my']` is **NOT** set, you don't set `$ali`, so the switch trying to run with an undefined symbol (`$ali` is not set and not defined).

Something like this would be better suited:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
    switch ($_POST['my']) {
        case '1':
            echo "one";
            break;
        case '2':
            echo "two";
            break;
        case '3':
            echo "three";
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This also fixes the problem, but does not explain the cause of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do :

```
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
 $ali = $_POST['my'];

 switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
  }

 }
```

The problem happen since you had

```
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
 $ali = $_POST['my']; 
}
```

and then you have used `$ali` in `switch()` so if the data is posted then its fine but if you just load the page it will not get any value of `$ali` and `$ali` is undefined resulting the error.

Comment: i was about click the "post your answer" button . and i saw that there is new answer :( . (y)

Comment: This fixes the problem, but does not explain WHY it happens

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way you can try it.

```
<?php

switch ($_POST['my']) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Doesn't match 1, 2 or 3";
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You check if $_POST['my'] is set. But if it's not, you go ahead anyway. This is what generates the notice.

In some cases it's desirable to do something if the $_POST['my'] is not set too. Stopping the switch case all together might not be the best thing to do.

My solution:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="my">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
    $ali = $_POST['my'];
}
else {
    $ali = -1;
}

switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
    default:
        echo "no match";
}
?>
```

This way $ali is always set, and you will not get a notice.

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem because if $_POST['my'] is NOT set, you don't set $ali, which you then use your switch on.

The simple answer would be to include the switch in the if:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="my">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
   $ali = $_POST['my'];

   switch ($ali) {
       case '1':
           echo "one";
           break;
       case '2':
           echo "two";
           break;
       case '3':
           echo "three";
           break;
   }
}
?>
```

Alternatively you can also put a default value for your $ali so you get at least some output:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="my">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
   $ali = $_POST['my'];
} else {
   $ali = '1'; // default value in case $_POST['my']  is NOT set
}
switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but in your code, you can use `default:` instead of `else {
   $ali = '1'; // default value in case $_POST['my']  is NOT set
}`

Comment: what is the default value if all cases in the switch statement fail.

Comment: True, you can indeed use a default in the switch. However if $_POST['my'] was not set, $ali would not be set, and even if the switch has a default clause, there would still be an error.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_POST` array activates or gets populated after you send a form with the `method=POST`. That is, when you click the submit button. Therefor, when the script executes before you click the submit button, the if expression in the if statement is false and doesn't get executed and execution goes on, using the $ali variable that doesn't exist. Put the switch statement inside the if statement.

Also, you have to check if the submit button name field exists because if that one is set, all the others are too. Also, it's good practice to use 'default' as the fallback when everything other is false in a switch statement. So the correct code is this...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_name_attribute'])) {
    $ali = (empty($_POST['my'])) ? '' : $_POST['my'];
    switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
       echo "one";
       break;
    case '2':
       echo "two";
       break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
        break;
    default:
        echo "no value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am coming late to the party, but I have a slightly different approach

```
<?php
$ali=(ISSET($_POST['my']))?$_POST['my']:"";
switch ($ali) {
    case '1':
        echo "one";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "two";
        break;
    case '3':
        echo "three";
    default:
        echo "no value";
}
?>
```

Not much different to the other answers, but I think the shorthand if statement is much neater. Basically if the $POST is not set it will put an empty value in $ali and then the default will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
first initialize $ali with some value like false which you can later check 
in switch-case.
for eg. :

```
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="my">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    $ali=false;

    if (isset($_POST['my'])) {
    $ali = $_POST['my'];
    }
    switch ($ali) {
        case '1':
            echo "one";
            break;
        case '2':
            echo "two";
            break;
        case '3':
            echo "three";
            break;
        case false:
            echo '$ali is\'t set';
            break;
        case '':
             echo '$ali is blank';
             break;

    }

?>
```